# What names do you use for the “Solution Platforms” in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, build, naming

The Visual Studio Default config says: “Any CPU”, does anybody change that? If so, what would you use and why?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2008, the x86 debugger is easier to use so I'll switch to use x86 while debugging, then go back to "Any CPU" when I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're going with your question. It says 'Any CPU' because it means to target 'Any CPU'. Can't find a better description for that, can you? If you want to be picky you could say 'Almost Any CPU' but that makes even less sense, beacuse people will start to wonder which CPUs it does not target.

In short: no I don't bother changing it unless I make a configuration for especially one cpu and then I'd name it to that CPU.